# Admin Page in Django won't load

Tags: python, django

I'm new with Django Framework, I've been following few tutorials and trying to create a website using Django 3.0.1 and Pythong 3.8
 when I crate my super user using:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I'm able to setup it up, but when I try to access: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/'
[Server can't be accessed(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvqx5.png)

This only happens when attempting to access after entering my username and passwords, as soon as I enter my credentials, the server stops.

This is what my urls.py under the project looks like:

> ```
> from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path, include
>
> admin.autodiscover()
>
> urlpatterns = [
> path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
> path('tokens/', include('tokens.urls')) ]
> ```

Does someone have an Idea of what the problem is?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py runserver` before visiting the admin page?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console that's running the `runserver` command?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin , Yes I did run the server

Comment: @HenryWoody , No!, that's the strange thing, I didn't get any error when server stops.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Is it activated? You can find out with `which python`

Comment: Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Don't you have any errors showing in your shell (where you are executing the server) when trying to reach the admin page? Did you make the initial migrations? If not, you can try `python manage.py makemigrations admin` then `python manage migrate`. Did you create custom models? Did you change your `settings.py` or `urls.py` file? What changes did you make regarding the initial tutorial?